# Yang-Mills action - a potential mistake in Wikipedia

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, conventions, yang-mills, normalization

Currently at the [Wikipedia page on Yang-Mills theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory#Mathematical_overview), you see that [a screenshot],

[image]

> Isn't that an obvious mistake? 
>   Based on this normal convention:
>   $$
> F^2 \equiv F \wedge \star F
> $$
>   Shouldn't it be:

$$
 -\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(F^2)\equiv
-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(F \wedge \star F)=
-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Tr}(F_{\mu \nu}  F^{\mu \nu})d^4x =- \frac{1}{4}
\operatorname{Tr}[T^a T^b] F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^b d^4x
$$
$$
=
- \frac{1}{4}
\frac{1}{2} \delta^{ab} F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^b d^4x
=- \frac{1}{8} \sum_a F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^a d^4x
=- \frac{1}{8} F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^a d^4x,
$$

where Einstein summation notation is assumed in the end. Based on the SU(N) Lie algebra, $\operatorname{Tr}[T^a T^b] =\frac{1}{2} \delta^{ab} $.
The $a,b$ are the indices for fundamental representation of SU(N). 
There is an overall factor mismatch between left and right hand side.

> $$
> \operatorname{Tr}(F^2)=\operatorname{Tr}(F \wedge \star F)=
> \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(F_{\mu \nu}  F^{\mu \nu})d^4x
> = \frac{1}{4} F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^ad^4x,
> $$
>   Alternatively, we can write
>   $$
> \operatorname{Tr}(F_{\mu \nu}  F^{\mu \nu})d^4x
> =
> \frac{1}{2} F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^ad^4x
> $$

For Maxwell theory, we have
$$
\mathcal{L}_\mathrm{Maxwell}d^4x = -\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(F^2)\equiv
-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Tr}(F \wedge \star F)=
-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Tr}(F_{\mu \nu}  F^{\mu \nu})d^4x=- \frac{1}{4}
\operatorname{Tr}[T^a T^b] F^{a\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}^b d^4x
$$
$$
= -\frac{1}{2}(F^2)=
-\frac{1}{2}(F \wedge \star F)=
- \frac{1}{4}
 F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}d^4x,
$$

Some correction on Wiki page is required if my above is correct.

Comment: Wikipedia is correct. Note that $\mathrm{tr}(F^2)\equiv \mathrm{tr}(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})$ instead of, as you wrote, $\mathrm{tr}(F^2)\overset{\mathrm{no}}=\color{red}{\frac12} \mathrm{tr}(F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu})$.

Comment: Thanks, then I guess it is the convention issue. Usually at the context I am familiar, we use
$$
F^2 \equiv F \wedge \star F
$$

Comment: @wonderich It is pretty common to use $T^2$ for the "standard" contraction of any tensor with itself (i.e. pairing first with first, second with second, etc, indices).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I like your equals sign with the "no" above it; how do you do that?

Comment: @probably_someone right click > show math as > TeX commands :-)